# Launching Activities Properly

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that has multiple activities, one activity opens the other and so on. I have a serious problem when it comes to returning to the previous activities. I want to return to the previous activity in the state I left it in(I do not want to recreate the activity). I was able to do so with three activities, but the fourth activity skips the third activity and returns to the second, for example:

> Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C -> Activity D

What I want when I press the back button and the Up button:

> Activity A <- Activity B <- Activity C <- Activity D

I initiate Activity A as a "singleTask", then I launch the next three activities like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
startActivity(intent);
```

This works perfectly with Activity B and C, but when I get to Activity D and try to return to Activity C, it takes me to Activity B instead of Activity C.

I have been through the internet and I just come seem to really understand the use of Intent flags and activity launch modes. Can someone please assist, pretty please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the launch modes and flags IS the problem. Maybe you'll want to assign activity A "singleTop", but you don't need to use flags when launching B, C, or D (at least not in the situation you're describing). Then pressing back will behave as you expect it to (unless you're overriding it).

Comment: when i remove the flags and launch modes, the previous activities get recreated when I press the up button

Comment: Is the back button working properly though? If you're implementing the Up button as well, here's a tutorial on that. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: managed to get it working by assigning single top to every activity, everything is working fine now